# How to survive and become self-sufficient in the nature?

Tags: technology, survival, engineering, agriculture

Brad and his family are tired of society and the concept of money. They want to live a primitive lifestyle. They need a strong, comfortable and cheap refuge that will protect them from the elements, insects and predators. Furthermore they need a source of food and a method to preserve it. What are the best crops and livestock for them in order to succeed?

Notes: Once they leave society they will never return. The refuge doesn't need to be that big. Technologies like hydroponics are allowed. The setting can be in any forested place or coast in mexican territory.

Comment: This looks like it is about a character, not about a world. This should be put on hold and edited.

Comment: @Secespitus Mmkay?

Comment: You could for example try to make it general like "How to survive with a group of 5 people in a forest with a flora and fauna like european forests of the current time for at least [x] months?". Would something like this be acceptabel?

Comment: The YouTube channel "[Primitive Technology](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAL3JXZSzSm8AlZyD3nQdBA)" is a good place to start.

Comment: @Secespitus i disagree. The question is not about the characters, but about the setting that would be required. Which, imho, is perfectly on-topic.

Comment: @Burki See [first revision](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/revisions/72687/1)  of this question. This is what Secespitus commented on.

Comment: Still, it's a story about one family to me. Set in an already built world (ours), even after edits.

Comment: @Molot Close my question,I dont care ;)

Comment: You should care about whether your question gets closed. The Worldbuilding SE is about more than just you. Each and every user contributes to the health of the site. If users stop caring about creating good, on-topic questions, the health of the entire site degrades, possibly to the point of extinction. Also, it's generally considered bad practice to accept an answer within the first few hours; doing so may discourage a better answer from showing up.

Comment: @Frostfyre Yes i know but i do it on porpouse to protect my question against hostile users,Good morning anyways.

Comment: @AlexDarkshine This kind of behaviour prevents users from helping you. You should listen to peopke with more Experience

Comment: @Secespitus Im sorry i always take personal this kind of thing...my apologies.

Comment: Accepting answers does not protect against any "hostilities". All it does is to say "I don't need any more answers". Close votes can follow, downvotes can follow. If you are feeling someone is hostile, please flag for moderator's attention.

Comment: @Secespitus There are plenty of of questions about specific characters, and even your suggested edit still is. Just because you remove the name and call it "a person" (or "5 people") doesn't really change anything. And the story might not even be about a specific person; it is entirely possible the story could be "a group of 5 people in a forest," but that the OP supplied a random name to change the feeling of the question - this is common on Worldbuilding and is often well regarded and accepted. Also one could say OP's question is building a world for Brad, mentioning him was extraneous data.

Comment: @Aaron As Molot said to Burki you should have a look at the first revision, which is what I commented on. And stories about specific characters are explicitly off-topic on WorldBuilding. [Help center: "What topics can I ask about here?"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) mentions under what you should not ask about: "Actions of individual characters, rather than elements of the world they inhabit".

Comment: @Secespitus Thank you for that information. I do find that concerning, however, as renders a LOT of the existing Worldbuilding questions off-topic, even some of the good ones. That would also put your suggested edit off-topic as well.

Comment: climate,altitude,habitat dependent anser. please state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find a comfortable cave for Brad.  I've always pondered what it would be like to live out in the wilderness.  A decent sized cave that leads to a dead end would be nice.  Foliage is essential for your survival.  If you have access to anything before your character leaves, get something like a shovel or an axe.  You'll need them.  Optimally, Brad will want to be able to complete everything he needs within the cave, including farming, keeping warm, feeding his family, and fending off predators.  Have Brad make primitive tools.  Considering that he's in the forest, there should be lots of trees.  With these trees, Brad can build comfortable shelter and more importantly, protection from the outside world for his cave.  The cave can be covered up with the wood, and possibly construct some sort of mechanism that works off a hinge, allowing for a door.
Now that Brad knows how to make a shelter, he needs to focus on food and surviving predators.  The predators part should be simple, considering Brad has primitive tool access, I'd imagine an axe would do fine.  Spears are preferable.
Are there any water sources or fish nearby in the forest?  Where your cave is in the world kind of answers this question.  If Brad can make spears, have him go fishing, he'll become avid, forced to adapt to the lifestyle.  He'll get better at spearing fish, and eventually be able to survive solely off of them.  There should be fruits, vegetables, etcetera in the forest, specifically berries.  These berries should serve to keep him hydrated, and if need be, foliage is a source of fiber.  Starvation is his biggest problem, everything else is easy.  Berries, fish, foliage, vegetables, a cave, primitive tools, trees, and a basic knowledge of farming are what Brad needs for survival.

Answer (score 0):

The answer relies strongly on the place in the world Brad want to go. 
Different crops and animals are suitable for Europe and different for Sub-Saharan region.
For easy answers read Bible. :)
Or Marvin Harris "Cows pigs wars and witches" - this will give you some base for agricultural choice and an idea of what restriction will be put on society you're trying to build.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the [stone age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Age).

Since you have left behind your comfortable life in suburbia, who needs modern society and money, you can only have what you make with your own two hands. Sorry, no power tools for you, or running water.

Maybe you have pets or livestock, but remember, our company was forced upon them during the [agricultural revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neolithic_Revolution). So if your beliefs run deep, you might need to start all over again...

**Basics:**

**First** we want water, you can go three days with out. So find a nice clean running stream. I hope you have a strong constitution Brad, [nasty stuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterborne_diseases) lives in there...

**Second** you will need to eat something. If you are in the right season you can get fruits and nuts. Grains and veggies need sowing, growing and tending. No serial for you, this year anyway. Meat? Good luck with that. I hope you know how to kill and clean an animal.

**Third** you need shelter against the elements. I hope you are good with your hands Brad. No tents or campers for you mate, that is way to modern for you. A cave would be nice. Or build something yourself with [wood](http://www.skilledsurvival.com/survival-shelters/).

**Other** I would put my money on Brad and family to return to society quite soon. There are some very good reasons to put up with money and stuff like that. Best bet on point of return: when someone gets ill with a preventable or curable disease. Better pre-pair yourself Brad, and buckle up, your comfy lifestyle is bye-bye.

Comment: "Other I would put my money on Brad and family to return to society quite soon," the asker stated that they were not coming back.

Comment: There is a difference in intending to never go back, and going back. When ideals and suffering loved ones cross one another, you get some interesting dynamics. Surviving in the wild is (generally) harder then modern society, so they might not be up to the task of thriving.

Comment: "Once they leave society they will never return"-Asker of question.

Comment: @NateDukes Dead people can't return to anything